# Detect a broken http connection in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node.js and Express in my app. I need to know if a connection is closed. But sometimes, the connection from client side is closed but no 'close' event is fired on `response` object.

The close event is attached to `response` object as soon as I receive it:

```
module.exports.getContent = (req, res) => {

  res.on('close', () => { console.log('Closed'); });

  readableStream.pipe(res);//readableStream is global
  .
  .
  .

}
```

`res` object receives data via pipe. I don't change any default values in `server` instance, `req` and `res`.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16443

As mentioned in the above link there is no direct way to identify if connection is broken or not.

Alternatively : keepAlive is an indication of whether the HTTP keep-alive mechanism is being used. It will not tell you the health of the current connection. Currently, there is no mechanism for determining if a connection is still active.